# Can produce to kafka topic even after configuring ACL

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm totally new to Kafka and i need to configured ACL for a topic and I've tried below:-

```
./kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 \ --add --allow-principal User:Bob \  --producer --topic newtopic
```

Ideally any producer other than Bob should not be allowed to produce on topic, but I'm able to produce to it with following Producer configuration.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("client.id", "DemoProducer");
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    producerConfig = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
    this.topic = topic;
    this.isAsync = isAsync;
```

Is there any more producer configuration needed to activate ACL, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Apollo : There may be lot of things.. you can block by ip address / user names and so on. One thing which I believe you have missed to add the below property in Server.properties

authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer

-- Adding this line would enable the ACL to work via SimpleAclAuthorizer. -- Kafka by default comes with the kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer defined by the parameter authorizer.class.name

you can try the below setup which might give complete idea.

https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-security-0.9